# How to download (stream) large (generated) file in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

In my app I'm generating large pdf/csv files.
 I'm wondering Is there any way to stream large files in Micronaut without keeping it fully in memory before sending to a client.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`StreamedFile`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/types/files/StreamedFile.html), eg:

```
@Get
public StreamedFile download() {
    InputStream inputStream = ...
    return new StreamedFile(inputStream, "large.csv");
}
```

Be sure to check [the official documentation about file transfers](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#transfers).

Comment: Thanks, but it would work only if the file is already generated and stored somewhere. But the problem is that I do not want to store. It would be great to stream it piece-by-piece during the generation process

Comment: @TarasKrutiak You can use a CircularByteBuffer